# MySQL looking for existing windows path

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am storing information about files that I read in from files in binary. I am using mysql to store the information. One of the columns is the absolute path of the file. This code will run periodically so I want to check that this specific file hasn't been parsed before.

I am trying to execute:

```
path = os.path.join(root,f)

sql = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Filepath = %s" % ("tntfiles", path)
```

But to no avail. I get an error saying: "1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

I've tried doing the same query with ` around the path:

```
path = "`" + path + "`'"
```

but I get: "1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wring because I can execute a similar query with

```
"SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Id = %s" % ("tntfiles","1")
```

and it works just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Try out [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). You will not regret using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL needs to have strings surrounded by ' or " - so just change the code to

```
"SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Filepath = '%s'" % ("tntfiles", path)
```

Comment: Did you mean to put a ' in front of Select also? And it yielded the same error

Comment: I meant this as the whole line. 
sql = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Filepath = '%s'" % ("tntfiles", path)

Answer (score 0):

```
path = os.path.join(root,f)

sql = "SELECT * FROM tntfiles WHERE Filepath = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (path,))
```

Otherwise your path values may not be properly quoted for special characters (though that's not likely), or may not be encoded correctly (more likely for Unicode and non-ASCII data).

If you absolutely must be able to substitute in different table names:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE Filepath = %%s" % ("tntfiles",)
cursor.execute(sql, (path,))
```